# Django db - lastrowid

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I cannot get the lastrowid after insert

```
def db_insert_lastrowid(sql, params=None):
    """Insert and return last row id"""
    with connections['default'].cursor() as c:
        with transaction.atomic(using='default'):
            sql = 'insert into test VALUES (%s, %s)'
            c.execute(sql, [11, '1'])
            re = c.fetchone()
            print(re)
    return True
```

With this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

I am using postgreSQL here and the the table is like:

```
### test table
id int4 nextval('auto_test'::regclass) 
name varchar
```

How can I get the last insert row id?
Another issue is that even I got this error, it still insert into the table without rollback.
Does it mean that I need to manually rollback when encounter an error?

Comment: Why do you use raw SQL instead of ORM?

Comment: I thought INSERT queries don't have any results that they return, so the error "no results to fetch" seems correct in this place

Comment: @Dmitry Because I don't like ORM. I am tired of learning different ORM syntax while using different frameworks across JAVA, SCALA, Python etc. I am using Django for a personal project and using RAW SQL would save me a lot of time.

Comment: @Ralf, but how to get lastrowid after insert without another query? Like the foloowing scenario: insert a row and get the id for the new row and then use the id as one of the params to insert into another table.    If I cannot get lastrowid, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer from PostgreSQL, we should use `RETURNING` and then use fetchone()

> INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets')
> RETURNING did;

> PostgreSQL currently advices to not create OIDs on the tables and the default for CREATE TABLE is to not support them. The INSERT ... RETURNING syntax available from PostgreSQL 8.3 allows more flexibility.